# Unix Remove all occurences of character and save

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How to remove all occurences of string "???" of a file and save it?

My approach so far:

```
cat file.txt | sed -ie '/s/???//' file.txt
```

However I get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `?'
```

Comment: @anubhava its part of file content

Comment: Then use: `sed 's/???//g' file.txt`

Comment: @anubhava Please add that as an answer, emphasizing that the `cat ... |` should *not* be used :) .  That's all I have to contribute, and isn't worth an answer by itself.  Thanks!

Comment: `sed`reads from stdin (the pipe `|`) when you do not give a file as an argument. You can remove the part before the pipe (and the first `/` in `/s/???//`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command:

```
sed -i 's/???//g' file.txt
```

There is no reason to use `cat` here as `sed` can directly operate on a file and save it in-line.

Also note that unlike other regex flavors BRE (Basic Regular Expressions) which is default regex engine of `sed` doesn't treat `?` as a special regex meta character hence there is no need to escape `?` here.

Comment: I think it's not only *no need* to escape the question mark, you even **must not** escape it. I'm not much experienced in sed, but from [this document](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) I conclude that escaping (prefixing with backslash) the question mark, you would actually turn it into a regexp operator; at least this applies to GNU sed.

Comment: Yes for GNU sed we must not escape question mark in the default BRE mode.